# wp_authenticate but not logged in

Tags: plugins, login, authentication

I am pretty new to all things Wordpress and seem to be really confused by what I have read.

What I am doing is creating a plugin for a specific job and I need to simply change the menu once logged in.  Now I am using DIVI 2 as a theme and I have this in the functions.php of the plugin:

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $args['menu'] = 'UserMenu';
} else {
    $args['menu'] = 'MainMenu';
}
return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

Which seems to make sense, but does not work and I am not sure if this is Divi2 or, as tested several times, the user is not logged in.  It keeps coming back as false `is_user_logged_in()`.

Here is the code I use for the custom login:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Andrew
 * Date: 08/11/2017
 * Time: 11:21
 */
global $wpdb;
$userOK = -1;
print_r(is_user_logged_in());
if(is_user_logged_in()) { //This does not action, ever!
    ?>
    <script>
     window.location.href = "https://URL.uk/userhome/";
    </script>
    <?php
}

if($_POST['wd_resendActivationButton'] === 'resend') {
    sendActivation($_POST['userid'], $_POST['useremail'],"2");
}

if($_POST['loginEmail'] && $_POST['loginPassword'] && !$_POST['wd_resendActivationButton']){
    $userOK = 0;
    $user = wp_authenticate( $_POST['loginEmail'] , $_POST['loginPassword'] );
    if(is_wp_error($user)) {
        echo $user->get_error_message();
    } else {
        if($user->user_status === "0") {
            wp_logout();
        } else {
            ?>
            <script>
                window.location.href = "https://url.uk/userhome/";
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```

As I understood it, `wp_authenticate` also logged the user in, but it seems to not do that.  So not sure where the issue lays.  Could someone please point me into the correct direction?

**UPDATE**

Using the below code, it is clear the wp_authentication is failing, although it does give me the user object, it does not log the user in:

```
    if($_POST['loginEmail'] && $_POST['loginPassword'] && !$_POST['wd_resendActivationButton']){
    $userOK = 0;
    $user = wp_authenticate( $_POST['loginEmail'] , $_POST['loginPassword'] );
    if(is_wp_error($user)) {
        echo $user->get_error_message();
    } else {
        if($user->user_status === "0") {
            wp_logout();
        } else {
            if(is_user_logged_in()) {
                ?>
                <script>
                    console.log('logged in');
                    window.location.href = "https://URL.uk/userhome/";
                </script>
                <?php
            } else {
                ?>
                <script>
                    console.log('Not logged in');
                    window.location.href = "https://URL.uk/";
                </script>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Addy

Comment: Where is the custom login code happening? If anything has been output to the page already then this is happening far too late, it needs to happen early so that headers can get sent, let us know where and when the code runs

Comment: @TomJNowell Hiya, thank you for your assistance.  I have updated the OP with the code from the Login.php  So this is a shortcode, as I do not use any of WP core login/registration stuff.

Comment: @TomJNowell Just, again, updated the code and it is clear the wp_authentication is not logging the user in.

Comment: I'm still not sure when this code runs, is that your `functions.php`? Where is the file included? Or is it a template? I cannot emphasise how important the *when* is, and where the code is ran, it's not enough to just see it without context.

Comment: @TomJNowell I will be honest I am not sure when the code runs.  This is a plugin and has it's own functions.php.  Not used the Themes function.php and thought the install and activation of the plugin would handle the load sequence.  Using Chrome Dev Screen I have been unable to see what loads first?

Comment: ah so it's running in the global scope at the root not on an init action or theme template. The chrome dev tools will only help you with frontend stuff, not PHP level stuff

Answer (score 2):

`wp_authenticate()` just checks user data, but not actually authenticating - [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate/).

You can use `wp_signon`, which uses and `wp_authenticate`: [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3/src/wp-includes/user.php#L33), like this:

```
    $credentials = [
        'user_login' => $name,
        'user_password' => $password,
        'rememberme' => true,
    ];

    $signon = wp_signon($credentials, true); // true - use HTTP only cookie

    if(is_wp_error($signon)){
        return false;
     }
     // The user is logged in redirect, return true, etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out what was causing it.  But I find it odd that there is such little information on it.  Anyway i hope this may help others in the future:

```
    if($_POST['loginEmail'] && $_POST['loginPassword'] && !$_POST['wd_resendActivationButton']){
    $userOK = 0;
    $user = wp_authenticate_username_password(NULL, $_POST['loginEmail'] , $_POST['loginPassword'] );
    wp_set_current_user($user->ID, $user->user_email);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
    do_action('wp_login', $user->user_email);
    if(is_wp_error($user)) {
        echo $user->get_error_message();
    } else {
        if($user->user_status === "0") {
            wp_logout();
            $userOK =1;
        } else {
            if(is_user_logged_in()) {
                $nonce = wp_create_nonce();
                function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {
                        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                            $args['menu'] = 'UserMenu';
                        }
                        return $args;
                    }
                    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
                ?>
                <script>
                    console.log('logged in');
                    window.location.href = "https://URL.uk/userhome?loggedin=true&_wpnonce=<?php echo $nonce; ?>";
                </script>
                <?php
            } else {
                ?>
                <script>
                    console.log('Not logged in');
                    window.location.href = "https://URL.uk/";
                </script>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would only add that I am not sure if the filter function for the menu needs to be here, or if I can place this back in Functions.php and use use the:

```
 add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

Not sure what is standard practice.  But it works.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: I added the following lines: ` wp_set_current_user($user->ID, $user->user_email);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
    do_action('wp_login', $user->user_email);`.  I also added the nonce to the end of the redirect link.  And I also added a filter for the menus.